# Php удаление блока Div по ID из файла

Tags: php

```
<div class='item-card' id="q1"></div>
```

Как удалить div из файла html по id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$html = file_get_contents('file.html');
$dom  = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html,  LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$el = $dom->getElementById('id');
$el->parentNode->removeChild($el);
```